# Winterbash knitting - fill mode doesn't work

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, winter-bash, winter-bash-2018

When I create a boundary such as:

[image]

and switch to fill mode:

[image]

and click inside the boundary, the entire screen is filled:

[image]

I expected only the area inside the boundary to be filled.

If I click outside the boundary, I get the same result.

If that's the intended functionality, it's not very useful. I had to use the "thick lines" mode in order to manually fill areas.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> If that's the intended functionality

It is. Its purpose is only for you to be able to start with a different background color than the default blue. An early version of the knitting simulator filled the whole thing with the current color just by clicking the bucket button, but that was a little too surprising, so we changed it to only fill upon clicking the canvas.

For the record, I said this:

[image: A Slack message by me, saying "Now I'm wondering if users familiar with drawing tools are going to expect a flood fill tool that respects color boundaries."]

Thanks for proving me right :)

> I had to use the "thick lines" mode in order to manually fill areas.

Anybody who has ever knitted an intricate pattern stitch-by-stitch is going to feel very sorry for you ;p

Comment: -1 for this being on purpose, +1 for being honest and funny. :-D

Comment: Seriously though, "fill" is really misleading. I'd go with "change background color" tooltip which sends a clearer message about the button goal.

Comment: @ShadowWizard agreed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I would suggest renaming the functionality from 'fill' to something that better describes the behavior. If not for the undo button, I would be in trouble after using 'fill'.

Comment: As for your last sentence, I'm sure "Anybody who has ever knitted an intricate pattern stitch-by-stitch" would love to have an "undo" button :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard agree also

Comment: Hehe what's going on? Why only people from Israel? :-P

Comment: C-c-c-combo breaker!

Comment: balpha should have called it [Phil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phil_Collins), as it behooves you to know that it marches to the beat of a [different drummer](https://youtu.be/2ft954vXPa4).